# How to select query count only once duplicate rows with MYSQL GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm building a very light weight web analytics software. The user select date range and can view how many unique and returning visitors. I'm trying to display unique visitors with `GROUP BY`. Problem with GROUP BY is that it does not remove duplicates. A visitor should only be counted once even if he visited twice on the same day. How to do this?

**What I have so far**

```
SELECT last_update, COUNT(ipAddress) as uniqueVisitor 
FROM geolocation 
WHERE last_update 
BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-12-01' 
GROUP BY date(last_update)
```

**This returns**

```
last_update          | uniqueVisitor
2020-11-11 19:29:45  | 3
2020-11-13 19:53:16  | 5
```

Each ipAddress should only be counted once per day.

**Desired result**

```
last_update          | uniqueVisitor
2020-11-11 19:29:45  | 2
2020-11-13 19:53:16  | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT last_update, COUNT(DISTINCT ipAddress) as uniqueVisitor 
FROM geolocation 
WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-12-01' 
GROUP BY date(last_update);
```

I would recommend not using just `last_update` in the `SELECT` -- the query should generate an error.  Instead:

```
date(last_update)
min(last_update)
max(last_update)
```